# How to mount/unmount react component instead of show/hide

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react question.

Basically, I have a component .

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
    <Child/> 
  )
 }
}
```

Notice that the parent is not passing anything to child, rather the child has its own props and state mapped through the redux store. The  is basically a modal which shows/hides and its actions are contained by different component. (Show/hide does not resets the state which is what I want every time I open the modal)

Since its not mounting/unmounting I dont have access to componentDidMount every time which I need.

My question is how to mount/unmount rather than show/hide since I dont care about preserving state values. I tried to do

```
  {this.props.showChild && <Child/>}
```

but that did not work either.

I read about the react reconciliation algorithm just cannot figure out how does it apply here

Comment: Why don't you just reset the state during the open/close function? That way you don't have to keep re-rendering it?

Comment: when you tried `{this.props.showChild && <Child/>}` how did you toggle `showChild` value?

Comment: `{this.props.showChild && <Child/>} ` if that props is true then false it will mount and unmount, so something else is wrong

Comment: @Jayce444 Right now I am resetting the state.(This does not run some react lifecycles like componentDidMount since its not mounting)            
ShowChild is a prop on Parent. The problem is by doing {this.props.showChild && <Child/>} it mounts immediately when the parent mounts, not on a action called.